# No Unity in lightdm after installing from software center!

Tags: unity

Hello I am using Ubuntu Studio 13.10 and I want to try Unity 7,
I installed Unity desktop from Software Center around 60mb, but there is not Unity in lightdm to select, did I missed something?

also in terminal when i type "unity" it comes up showing it is there.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

This is the content of my /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

If for some reason you don't have it, create a new one:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu2.desktop
```

And fill it with the content. You can change the name to ubuntu2.desktop for the file, and the Name=Unity-test just in case if you don't want to overwrite other files.

When you're done, restart or just log out and log in, or from a terminal:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

And see if the new item shows up.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @darent but does not working, screen is empty, I used also on Exec=unity it comes up but very ugly and no menues. should i install gnome, i did before and it worked but i like unity here.

Comment: Then the problem is not the launcher but some graphic or system problem, because that's the session launcher I'm using. You could try to reinstall unity and install other desktops like gnome-shell, see if you can log in. Also, you could create a new user and try to log-in with him, or log in as a guest, to see if the problem is caused by a local misconfiguration.

Comment: Not working, even i installed Gnome-shell.